# Why does $X$ appear to have normal distribution where $X|Y \sim N(Y, |Y|)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for large $\mu$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Simulating this $X$ gives very close adherence to a normal distribution, but I can't find a good justification. I've tried 3 things that I couldn't get to work:

- Various CLT arguments.
- MGFs.
- normal-inverse-Wishart conjugate prior.

I'm quite certain that $X$ is not normally distributed, so I'm not looking for a proof, just some justification. Also I'm using the notational convention $\text{Var}(X|Y) = |Y|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, this is because $Y = \mu + “\mathcal{O}(\sigma)”$ for large $\mu$ and fixed $\sigma$. This suggests that the distribution of $X$ is close to $\mathcal{N}(\mu, |\mu|)$, explaining why $X$ looks like normally distributed.

To give the proof, let us consider the normalized random variable $ Z = \frac{X - \mu}{|\mu|^{1/2}} $. Then the PDF of $Z$ can be computed by

\begin{align*}
f_Z(z)
&= |\mu|^{1/2} f_X(\mu + z |\mu|^{1/2}) \\
&= |\mu|^{1/2} \mathbf{E} \biggl[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi |Y|}} e^{-(\mu + z |\mu|^{1/2}-Y)^2/2|Y|} \biggr]
\end{align*}

Writing $Y = \mu + \sigma \xi$ for $\xi \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, this further reduces to

\begin{align*}
f_Z(z)
&= \mathbf{E} \biggl[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi |1 + (\sigma \xi/\mu)|}} e^{-[z - (\sigma \xi / |\mu|^{1/2})]^2 / 2 \lvert 1 + (\sigma \xi/\mu) \rvert } \biggr].
\end{align*}

With $\sigma$ fixed and as $|\mu| \to \infty$, we can show that this converges to

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E} \biggl[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2} \biggr]
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2} = \phi(z),
\end{align*}

the PDF of the standard normal distribution. Therefore $Z$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ as $|\mu| \to \infty$.

Comment: Empirically, I am not sure you need to fix $\sigma$ when increasing $\mu$ if you suitably adjust for the actual variance of $X$,  With $\mu=1$ then both $\sigma=1$ and $\sigma=10$ produce distributions which are far too peaked.  But I cannot see anything similar with $\mu=100$ and any $\sigma$, and it would not surprise me if things improved further as $\mu$ got even bigger

Comment: @Henry, Fixing $\sigma$ is more of convenience. Indeed, the formula above tells that if $|\mu| \to \infty$ and $\sigma = o(|\mu|^{1/2})$, then the $Z$ will still converge in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Comment: Indeed, but my point is that  it seems that this also holds if $\sigma=|\mu|$ or $|\mu|^2$ or anything else, so long as you take account of the higher variance of $X$ which might then be a lot bigger than $|\mu|$

Comment: @Henry, That's a good point. :) Perhaps the true mechanism is that we have $$X = Y + \mathcal{O}_p(|Y|^{1/2}) = Y\left( 1 + \mathcal{O}_p(|Y|^{-1/2}) \right) $$ as long as $|Y|$ is "typically" big.